# DIY External Powered USB hub not working

Tags: usb, power-supply, usb-power

I have put together a DIY External Powered USB Hub by following the instructions. ([Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Adding-an-external-power-supply-to-a-cheap-USB-hub/), [htc-linux](http://htc-linux.org/wiki/index.php?title=DIY-usb-hub))

- USB hub with 4 ports
- 5v 2A AC/DC power supply (It varies when tested with multimeter, 5.3 ~ 5.5)

[image: DIY hub]

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Here is the `lsusb -v` I try plugging Logitech K260 and Netgear N150 - WNA1100 wireless adaptor, nothing was detected when connecting via Hub. I couldn't figure the issue, I tested for the connectivity of of the 4 points (`+5 D+ D- GND`), seems to be working.

I would like to use my Netgear N150 instead of LAN cable. Though it is detected if connected directly, it doesn't connect. I assume it is due to power requirement, it is the reason why I built this USB hub in first place.

Here is the output from `lsusb -v`

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.02
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         2 TT per port
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0424 Standard Microsystems Corp.
  idProduct          0x9512 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Single TT
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 TT per port
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0424 Standard Microsystems Corp.
  idProduct          0xec00 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               4

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc52e 
  bcdDevice           23.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     177
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0014  1x 20 bytes
        bInterval               2
```

Here is the output from `dmesg`

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dmesg

[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.27+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct 18 19:03:02 BST 2012
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine: BCM2708
[    0.000000] Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 114688
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c050db28, node_mem_map c05b6000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 896 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 113792 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113792
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1280 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=960 bcm2708.boardrev=0xf bcm2708.serial=0x496c5807 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:6C:58:07 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=100000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1c000000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 448MB = 448MB total
[    0.000000] Memory: 448872k/448872k available, 9880k reserved, 0K highmem
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xdc800000 - 0xe8000000   ( 184 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdc000000   ( 448 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc04c0e78   (4836 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc04c1000 - 0xc04e0b10   ( 127 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc04e2000 - 0xc050e1c0   ( 177 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc050e1e4 - 0xc05b5128   ( 668 kB)
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:330
[    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 4294967ms
[    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:1
[    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:3
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000000] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000945] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
[    0.060149] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.060629] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[    0.061122] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.061213] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.061250] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.061281] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.061425] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.061761] hw perfevents: enabled with v6 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    0.062971] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.073313] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.074002] bcm2708.uart_clock = 0
[    0.075626] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.075683] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.075722] mailbox: Broadcom VideoCore Mailbox driver
[    0.075829] bcm2708_vcio: mailbox at f200b880
[    0.075933] bcm_power: Broadcom power driver
[    0.075972] bcm_power_open() -> 0
[    0.075997] bcm_power_request(0, 8)
[    0.576677] bcm_mailbox_read -> 00000080, 0
[    0.576717] bcm_power_request -> 0
[    0.576743] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.576897] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 83) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.886920] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.912419] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.917627] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.921628] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.927355] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.932938] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.938976] Switching to clocksource stc
[    0.943226] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.946405] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.963138] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.967972] IP route cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.976142] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.984176] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.991130] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    0.997741] TCP reno registered
[    1.000913] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.006828] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.013642] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.018775] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.024911] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.029636] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.034388] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.041131] bcm2708_dma: DMA manager at dc808000
[    1.045933] bcm2708_gpio: bcm2708_gpio_probe c04e9c18
[    1.051390] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1c000000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    1.060684] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    1.066233] type=2000 audit(0.750:1): initialized
[    1.182313] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    1.186558] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.194098] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.200356] msgmni has been set to 876
[    1.206206] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.210176] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    1.215622] io scheduler cfq registered
[    1.253626] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x60
[    1.276826] kgdb: Registered I/O driver kgdboc.
[    1.291227] brd: module loaded
[    1.299534] loop: module loaded
[    1.303649] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xffd80000, is_master = 0
[    1.311258] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: called
[    1.316775] vcos: [1]: vchiq: initialised - version 2 (min 2), device 252.0
[    1.324714] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.330678] cdc_ncm: 04-Aug-2011
[    1.334174] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.339984] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.551051] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.554415] Setting default values for core params
[    1.559368] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.770233] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.773684] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.779652] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.785389] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.789865] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.793695] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    1.793741] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.798806] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.806317] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.812011] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.816155] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.819597] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.826619] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.839977] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.850797] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.27+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.862669] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
[    1.874163] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.884033] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.894615] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.894634] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.894656] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.895005] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.906304] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    1.917357] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.929290] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    1.940073] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    1.952138] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.964493] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=700000 cur=700000
[    1.970330] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
[    1.981898] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
[    1.993668] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    2.009496] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    2.019482] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.031519] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.041803] sdhci: Enable low-latency mode
[    2.051708] bcm_power_open() -> 1
[    2.060999] Registered led device: mmc0::
[    2.062477] mmc0: SDHCI controller on BCM2708_Arasan [platform] using platform's DMA
[    2.076278] mmc0: BCM2708 SDHC host at 0x20300000 DMA 2 IRQ 77
[    2.088087] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.100874] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.112101] Registered led device: led0
[    2.112513] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.129908] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.163341] TCP cubic registered
[    2.183367] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.213143] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.224882] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    2.240738] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register.
[    2.263077] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    2.277775] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.288096] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    2.301035] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    2.316319] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.328407] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SU08G 7.40 GiB 
[    2.340732]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.373050] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.385612] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.443333] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.473045] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    2.502353] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.512196] Freeing init memory: 124K
[    2.633517] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[    2.647168] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.663933] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.673875] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.963334] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.093692] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    3.093717] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.122375] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    3.188619] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:6c:58:07
[    3.303344] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.446425] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52e
[    3.464100] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.477922] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Receiver
[    3.488731] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    3.512246] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input0
[    3.552705] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52E.0001: input: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input0
[    3.602865] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/input/input1
[    3.634049] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52E.0002: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input1
[    4.145709] udevd[137]: starting version 175
[   10.612250] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   11.130347] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   11.916388] bcm2835 ALSA card created!
[   11.940583] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   11.957208] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   11.970944] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   11.984700] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   12.003362] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   12.023442] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   12.042056] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   16.612997] mmc0: missed completion of cmd 18 DMA (512/512 [1]/[1]) - ignoring it
[   16.627416] mmc0: DMA IRQ 6 ignored - results were reset
[   20.633741] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   23.976991] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SS
[  340.933405] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  343.493475] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  346.053492] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  348.453463] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  350.923518] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  353.483453] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  356.043399] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  358.603458] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  361.163388] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  363.723483] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  366.283406] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  368.843473] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  371.403416] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  373.963476] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  376.523418] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  379.083486] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  381.643547] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  384.203489] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  386.603410] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  389.073464] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
..
..
..
..
[ 1562.719882] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[ 1565.280058] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[ 1567.840249] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[ 1570.400439] hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
```

Comment: Anything reported by `dmesg`?

Comment: @Jivings updated the question with dmesg output.

Comment: `hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled`: This almost certainly represents a power issue.

Comment: any resources to understand more about the issue?

Comment: You were supposed to solder the power on the PCB - Not mid way on the USB wire. That just causes serious issues with Data because you mess with the shield and cause noise that is not expected. Does it work in windows? If not. Bin it, thats your lesson learnt and paid for. Then, do it properly...(I suspect there are diodes missing also.. ehh)

Comment: I'm using a 7 port external powered usb hub.
I cut the 2 data wires from the power cord and the 2 power wires from the usb->raspberry cord.
With windows the hub works fine but with the rasp I have a lot of
hub 1-1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled As said before, cord modification could be the problem?

Comment: as long as I know you dont cut BOTH power cables. To create a communication you need a common GND

Comment: @AwesomeUser done. I ended up buying a external powered USB adapter as my DIY failed. And I accepted an answer closer to the one.

Comment: WNA 1100 is highspeed(480 mbps) usb device.
while the hub might be a full speed device(12 mbps) try lsusb -t option Also tail /var/log message while connecting the usb device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating the usb cable is not a good idea, as, in consideration of the high frequencies involved, it must be considered a transmission line (*) to all effects: in the best case (i.e. very very very clean work AND very very very good luck) you get some performance downgrading. It is possible that you got nearer to the worst case than to the best one.

The htc-linux procedure seems more reliable than the instructables one. Of course in the framework of a very very very clean work.

(*) Note: the key feature of a transmission line is translational symmetry. Any symmetry breakdown causes signal reflections.

Answer (score 2):

It may be over voltage. When they say the USB spec is 5 V it's usually much closer than 5.3. The fact that the power supply ranges so much isn't a good sign. It could be causing continued resets on the Wi-fi or activating its over-voltage protection. Try to see if you can clean up the power-supply's output some (or try a phone charger temporarily?). A 5 V Zener diode should protect more from the over-voltage at least.

Comment: USB spec is pretty clear about this: 5V line should be between 4.75 and 5.25V, anything substantially out of this range (like 5.5V) is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help, but this one is the most pathetic USB hub that one can get. I had to discard two of these before I switched to a better one, and voila! everything worked!
So, try replacing this (such) hub with a better one, and see.
Also, you might want to plug-in the WiFi adapter directly to Pi, and use this hub for other miscellaneous devices with lower power requirements. I assume the wireless mouse requires much less power than the WiFi adapter.

Comment: Yes wireless keyboard/mouse require only 96mA and wifi needs only 500mA. I have replaced the usb to go with 2A adaptor to rPi. But having issue with driver now - http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/setting-up-netgear-n150-usb-wifi-adapter-with-raspberrypi-wheezy