# Setting up Netgear N150 USB wifi adapter with RaspberryPi wheezy

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

After my failed attempt with [DYI powered USB](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4344/diy-external-powered-usb-hub-not-working) hub. I managed to power my Netgear N150 directly with RPi native port by supplying 2A 5+V DC to RPi. However, I was not able to connect/configure wifi successfully.

Though power seems to be not an issue anymore, I can scan for network and configure, but i was not able to connect to my network. When I tap on connect, i can see 'Failed to initiate AP Scan' message in the progress.

Find output of `lsusb`, `iwlist scan` and `ifconfig` below.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9030 NetGear, Inc. WNA1100 Wireless-N 150 [Atheros AR9271]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:0902 Atmel Corp. 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc.
```

--

```
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
         Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:33:25:C2:94
                   Channel:11
                   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                   Quality=70/70  Signal level=-24 dBm  
                   Encryption key:on
                   ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                   Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                             12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                   Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                   Mode:Master
                   Extra:tsf=00000000c3bd6181
                   Extra: Last beacon: 3700ms ago
                   IE: Unknown: 000E0000000000000000000000000000
                   IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                   IE: Unknown: 03010B
                   IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                   IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                   IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                   IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                       Group Cipher : CCMP
                       Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                       Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                      Preauthentication Supported

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

pi@raspberrypi /boot $
```

--

```
pi@raspberrypi /boot $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:6c:58:07  
         inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:10096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:7485 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:9304609 (8.8 MiB)  TX bytes:829233 (809.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:3d:c7:bc:34:db  
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

pi@raspberrypi /boot $
```

--
Find my `dmesg` output below:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dmesg
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.27+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct 18 19:03:02 BST 2012
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine: BCM2708
[    0.000000] Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 114688
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c050db28, node_mem_map c05b6000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 896 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 113792 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113792
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1280 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=960 bcm2708.boardrev=0xf bcm2708.serial=0x496c5807 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:6C:58:07 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=100000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1c000000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 448MB = 448MB total
[    0.000000] Memory: 448872k/448872k available, 9880k reserved, 0K highmem
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xdc800000 - 0xe8000000   ( 184 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdc000000   ( 448 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc04c0e78   (4836 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc04c1000 - 0xc04e0b10   ( 127 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc04e2000 - 0xc050e1c0   ( 177 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc050e1e4 - 0xc05b5128   ( 668 kB)
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:330
[    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 4294967ms
[    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:1
[    0.000000] timer_set_mode: unhandled mode:3
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000000] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000946] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
[    0.060146] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.060627] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[    0.061122] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.061214] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.061250] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.061282] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.061425] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.061764] hw perfevents: enabled with v6 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    0.062978] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.073358] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.074046] bcm2708.uart_clock = 0
[    0.075666] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.075723] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.075761] mailbox: Broadcom VideoCore Mailbox driver
[    0.075865] bcm2708_vcio: mailbox at f200b880
[    0.075970] bcm_power: Broadcom power driver
[    0.076008] bcm_power_open() -> 0
[    0.076033] bcm_power_request(0, 8)
[    0.576719] bcm_mailbox_read -> 00000080, 0
[    0.576761] bcm_power_request -> 0
[    0.576786] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.576954] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 83) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.886984] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.912500] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.917710] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.921709] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.927437] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.933023] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.939061] Switching to clocksource stc
[    0.943311] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.946495] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.963256] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.968093] IP route cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.976268] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.984315] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.991271] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    0.997880] TCP reno registered
[    1.001054] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.006969] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.013786] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.018926] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.025062] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.029786] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.034538] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.041283] bcm2708_dma: DMA manager at dc808000
[    1.046082] bcm2708_gpio: bcm2708_gpio_probe c04e9c18
[    1.051539] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1c000000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    1.060837] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    1.066388] type=2000 audit(0.750:1): initialized
[    1.182825] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    1.187072] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.194616] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.200876] msgmni has been set to 876
[    1.206738] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.210708] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    1.216149] io scheduler cfq registered
[    1.253113] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x60
[    1.276445] kgdb: Registered I/O driver kgdboc.
[    1.290863] brd: module loaded
[    1.299188] loop: module loaded
[    1.303337] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xffd80000, is_master = 0
[    1.310936] vcos: [1]: vchiq_init_state: called
[    1.316451] vcos: [1]: vchiq: initialised - version 2 (min 2), device 252.0
[    1.324392] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.330360] cdc_ncm: 04-Aug-2011
[    1.333854] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.339666] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.550736] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.554099] Setting default values for core params
[    1.559050] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.769914] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.773365] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.779334] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.785070] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.789549] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.793379] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    1.793426] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.798491] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.806002] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.811695] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.815845] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.819289] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.826311] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.839712] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.850613] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.27+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.862563] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
[    1.874119] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.884056] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.894709] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.894728] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.894751] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.895098] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.906463] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    1.917567] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.929547] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    1.940379] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    1.952501] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.964925] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=700000 cur=700000
[    1.970764] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
[    1.982389] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor powersave
[    1.994200] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    2.010159] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    2.020189] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.032326] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.042656] sdhci: Enable low-latency mode
[    2.052605] bcm_power_open() -> 1
[    2.061956] Registered led device: mmc0::
[    2.063428] mmc0: SDHCI controller on BCM2708_Arasan [platform] using platform's DMA
[    2.077246] mmc0: BCM2708 SDHC host at 0x20300000 DMA 2 IRQ 77
[    2.089095] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.101928] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.113349] Registered led device: led0
[    2.119124] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.142743] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.174277] TCP cubic registered
[    2.185075] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.200528] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register.
[    2.223123] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.239098] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    2.254394] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.273179] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    2.287655] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SU08G 7.40 GiB
[    2.298995] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.310172] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    2.322938]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.354302] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.368527] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    2.389041] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.398956] Freeing init memory: 124K
[    2.408740] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.421924] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.633788] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[    2.647140] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.661806] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.672589] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.963569] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.083788] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    3.109903] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.133545] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    3.208733] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:6c:58:07
[    3.323343] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.474859] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9030
[    3.500104] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[    3.533174] usb 1-1.2: Product: WNA1100
[    3.548817] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: NETGEAR WNA
[    3.572360] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 12345
[    3.683381] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.825123] usb 1-1.3: string descriptor 0 read error: -32
[    3.841188] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=0902
[    3.854738] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.870867] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.881604] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    4.038197] udevd[137]: starting version 175
[    4.173482] usb 1-1.3.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[    4.336550] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52e
[    4.382772] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.398898] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: USB Receiver
[    4.410226] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    4.442791] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/input/input0
[    4.498464] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52E.0001: input: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3.2/input0
[    4.552277] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.1/input/input1
[    4.583568] generic-usb 0003:046D:C52E.0002: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3.2/input1
[    7.078600] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    8.025601] usb 1-1.2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51272
[    8.261277] ath9k_htc 1-1.2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[    8.492551] ath9k_htc 1-1.2:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.3
[    8.505945] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    8.505967] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    8.506001] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    8.506012] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    8.539828] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
[    8.554521] Registered led device: ath9k_htc-phy0
[    8.554556] usb 1-1.2: ath9k_htc: USB layer initialized
[    8.571317] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   12.175286] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   12.666760] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   13.499995] bcm2835 ALSA card created!
[   13.524013] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.548348] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.569997] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.586161] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.599910] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.613618] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   13.627068] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   22.710641] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   27.054842] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SS
```

[image: Failed to initiate AP Scan]

[image: Network config]

[image: Scanning]

**Update Feb 22**

I couldn't make it to work even with external powered USB hub. Same "*Failed to initiate AP Scan*" but "Scan" functionality works. Issue is only with connecting to a access point.

[image: My usb wifi adapter]

**Update Aug'13 2013**

Three words [NOOBS](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4100%E2%80%8E) is awesome. The recent version of Raspbian installed with NOOBS is working out of the box without any additional steps.

Not sure it is the version comes with [NOOBS v.1.2](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/noobs) package, I have tried apt-get upgrade to update my installed version of Raspbian and was not successful.

Note: Still It doesn't work with hidden SSID.

Comment: It looks pretty good up to the connecting part. It would be nice to see some real messages. You might look at (tail -f) `/var/log/auth.log` and `daemon.log` (other logfiles, too) and see if anything interesting pops up there while you try to connect to your network.

Comment: Are the settings in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` correct? [Maybe this helps](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/wlan-using-netgear-wna1000m-fails-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: What kind of wifi network do you have?

Comment: Netgear WGR614v7 router configured with WPA2 personal

Answer (score 1):

I got my `Netgear N150` working by adding `ap_scan=0` to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Your dmesg says that you're using a WNA1100 dongle. Try this post:   http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=21569

Comment: yep I tried it without any luck. I have also tried the ap_scan=0 which dyret mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Raspbian on Raspberry Pi2.

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705042/netgear-n150-wireless-usb-stick-not-working-with-raspbian-wheezy-on-my-pi) from Mirko Sertic solved my problem.
Here are the steps even for Linux newbies :

- Open a terminal (black icon)
- Type `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
- Type following 4 lines just before `exit 0`

```
modprobe 8192cu  
echo "0846 9043" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id  
ifdown wlan0  
ifup wlan0
```

- Do a Ctrl+X to save, answer Y for Yes, and hit enter to validate filename
- Edit another file: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/netgear_n150.conf`

and type this line:

```
install 8192cu /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install 8192cu; echo "0846 9043" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

- Ctrl+X, Yes, Enter
- Type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart your raspberry
- Launch Wifi connection Gui by typing 'wpa_gui' in terminal (I don't know where the icon is). Selected adapter should be "wlan0", and nothing is displayed in "Network"
- Click on "scan" in the bottom of the window
- You obtain a list of Wifi access points.
- Double click on the name of yours, and enter security settings
- Click on "Add", close list window
- It should display "Status : Completed (station)". Click on "connect"
- Do a "File / Save configuration" (I'm not sure of that).
- You could now "connect" to your Wifi spot
- When connected, my NetGear key blinks with a blue light
- you could check your ip with the command `ifconfig`

Comment: Hello and welcome! You did not do it wrong. Somehow formatting does not work properly in lists...